# Remain state (collapse/expand) of child in navigation menu when collapsing navigation menu

Tags: oracle-apex, navigationbar

I'm working on Oracle Apex 23.1 and have trouble with display of navigation bar.
For example, I have a tree as following:

```
node1 
  |_ sub-node2 
  |_ sub-node3
node4
```

I expand node1 by clicking on `>`, then I collapse the whole navigation bar (collapse the text but keep displaying icon of each node). I expect to see the icon of sub-node2 and sub-node3 are still displaying in collapsed menu.
However, I observed that there were only icons of node1 and node4 displayed in the collapsed menu.

Is there any way to keep icon of sub-node displaying?

Thanks in advance for any help and Merry Christmas.